# Как правильно построить navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android

Такой вопрос, у меня есть проект который выполнен НЕ на фрагментах и в который я хочу имплементировать `navigation drawer` , предается ли мне для этого переделывать весь проект на фрагменты для корректной работы `navigation drawer`?

Так как я слышал, что если имплементировать `navigation drawer` без фрагментов, то он будет тормозить при открывании и работать не корректно.

Но я попробовал создать несколько активити с `navigation drawer`  "так сказать из коробки", при создании студия сама предлагает такую фичу, и я нормально переключаюсь между ними и все работает.

Кто разбирается скажите все ли будет работать корректно если выполнить имплементацию navigation drawer без фрагментов и вообще насколько это связано?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё это никак не связано. Ничто не мешает вам сделать несколько активити и из дравера запускать активити, вместо смены фрагментов.

Возможно, под снижением быстродействия имели в виду лишь то, что поменять фрагмент быстрее, чем сменить активити.

Comment: Ок, понятно. Но почему почти во всех примерах такие манипуляции делают с использованием фрагментов?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ну, я думаю, потому, что обычно на фрагментах отображают схожую инфу и нет смысла под них активити делать. А вот настройки какие-нить и/или запуск камеры логичнее в другой активити сделать, т.к. это, обычно, к инфе с главной активити слабо относится. Типа идёт разделение по типу контента/действия.